# Manipulate NavigatorIOS route on a component

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I'm trying to build a very simple Todo application in React Native. It's composed of two views : one with a list of tasks, one with an input field (to add a new one). Navigation is assured by a `NavigatorIOS` and buttons on it (which would have been `UIBarButtonItem` with UIKit).

On the list view, there is a *Add* right button on Navigator, on the view with the text field, there the back button on the left and a *Done* one on the right. When clicking on done, it should add a new task with content of text field.

Problem is, **buttons and their actions are defined when creating the `NavigatorIOS` component**, and I don't find a way to attach a method defined in another component as a button action.

As an example, here is my `NavigatorIOS`

```
class TodoList extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <NavigatorIOS
                ref="nav"
                style={styles.navbar}
                initialRoute={{
                    component: ItemList,
                    title: 'Todo list',
                    rightButtonTitle: 'Add',
                    onRightButtonPress: () => {
                        this.refs.nav.push({
                            title: 'Add a new task',
                            component: AddTodo,
                            rightButtonTitle: 'Done',
                            onRightButtonPress: () => {
                                console.log('done !');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

I don't put here my two other components `ItemList` and `AddTodo` as there is nothing interesting on it.

What I need is a way to make components communicate (like in delegation pattern) with the navigation component.

Perhaps it's not possible, or I am totally wrong on the paradigm used with React Native, so feel free to comment if something is not clear on my question.

**Edit 05/26**

Actually, Facebook team is aware that something is missing to handle that use case with `NavigatorIOS` component.

From [Eric Vicenti](https://github.com/ericvicenti) (posted on February 3 2015) on [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31) that exactly covers my question.

> Currently the best way to do that is to create an `EventEmitter` in the owner of the `NavigatorIOS`, then you can pass it down to children using `route.passProps`. The child can mix in `Subscribable.Mixin` and then in `componentDidMount`, you can
>
> ```
> this.addListenerOn(this.props.events, 'myRightBtnEvent', this._handleRightBtnPress);
> ```
>
> It is clear that this API needs improvement. We are actively working the routing API in Relay, and hopefully react-router, but we want NavigatorIOS to be usable independently. Maybe we should add an event emitter inside the navigator object, so child components can subscribe to various navigator activity:
>
> ```
> this.addListenerOn(this.props.navigator.events, 'rightButtonPress', this._handleRightBtnPress);
> ```

Comment: I have run into this exact same architecture issue and have solved it by extending the NavigationBar such that I can define the actions in the child component.  I have also investigated the possibility of utilizing events such that the parent is emitting menu click events and the child can listen for the events and take action, not sure that is the correct approach, interested to see what others say.

Comment: @AaronSaunders Hi thanks for your comment! Did you extend `NavigatorIOS`, or `NavigationBar` is an inner component of `NavigatorIOS` ? I tried to extend the navigator, but as callbacks are on `initialRoute` prop (and deeper), I don't get how to expose them.

Answer (score 1):

A. In initial component

```
this.props.navigator.push({
    title: 'title',
    component: MyComponent,
    rightButtonTitle: 'rightButton',
    passProps: {
        ref: (component) => {this.pushedComponent = component},
    },
    onRightButtonPress: () => {
        // call func
        this.pushedComponent && this.pushedComponent.myFunc();
    },
});
```

B. In pushed component 
replace onRightButtonPress func in pushed component.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    // get current route
    var route = this.props.navigator.navigationContext.currentRoute;
    // update onRightButtonPress func
    route.onRightButtonPress =  () => {
        // call func in pushed component
        this.myFunc();
    };
    // component will not rerender
    this.props.navigator.replace(route);
},
```